# How to show background image in a list view in Android?

Tags: android, android-listview

When I create list view background becomes white.

I want to show list view over my background image so that background image can be displayed. My list view is created and working fine but it is showing background image white.

Comment: Please show the relevant code that you have tried.  Without details, it will be difficult to help you with your problem.

Comment: I got my solution from below answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <ListView   android:id = "@+id/listQueue"
                android:layout_width = "fill_parent"
                android:layout_height = "fill_parent"
                android:background = "@drawable/background"  //change this to your image
                android:divider="@drawable/separator"
                android:scrollingCache="false"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: @PravalSharma upvote answers if they are helpful and/or accept them if they solve your problem

Comment: [Help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) [people](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) and earn [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/site-moderators) then you can [upvote](http://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote) and get more [privileges](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) :-) good luck